# Stop New Mail Alert for emails on which rules applied in lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I have new mail alert set up in my lotus notes 8.5 version. So whenever I receive a new email, there is a small dialog/popup box open up.

I dont want this alert to be shown for the emails that are routed to a custom DELETE folder via a RULE I have setup.

Please advice what setting has to be done?

Thanks

Comment: Any advise on above or is there any other forum where I can get help on lotus notes?

Comment: The proper forum within the StackExchange network is SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to achieve this in lotus Notes, confirmed with our admin. Hence closing this